# Convert .kml to .txt files

Tags: kml

I´m working with GMT and have several kml files that I would like to convert to .txt files to include them in the plot. I know that there is a way to convert kml2txt in one of the versions of GMT, but I have a older version. Does anyone know of another way of converting these files?

Comment: .kml is already a text file???

Comment: Do the "KML" files have .kml file extension or .kmz? The latter form is a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

If want to convert KML to "text", you may want to try a KML to CSV converter, which converts the metadata for each placemark extracted into individual fields with one row per placemark. You can then view/edit/filter the CSV in Excel or any application that can open a CSV file.

http://www.convertcsv.com/kml-to-csv.htm

For example:

Input KML:

```
<Placemark>
  <TimeStamp>
    <when>2007-01-14T21:05:02Z</when>
  </TimeStamp>
  <styleUrl>#paddle-a</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-122.536226,37.86047,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Output CSV:

```
TimeStamp/when,styleUrl,longitude,latitude,altitude
2007-01-14T21:05:02Z,#paddle-a,-122.536226,37.86047,0
```

Note if the source "KML" file is compressed as a "KMZ" file then you can treat the KMZ file as a ZIP file and unzip it with any ZIP utility. Simply rename the .kmz file to .zip and use your favorite zip utility to unpack the KML file.

There are many different KML2CSV converters available but this one is online (no install required) and seems to do the job well enough except only point geometries are currently supported.